# `Unresolved reference: android` on new Flutter project

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter

My first Flutter app seems to be debugging okay so far on my phone, but all of a sudden I'm seeing this error in my `android/app/src/main/kotlin/my.appname.whatever/MainActivity` file (screenshot below).

And when I rollover the `onCreate`, it shows this:
`Cannot access class 'android.Os.Bundle'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies.`

I'm using AndroidStudio 3.2.1

While trying to get Firebase going, I changed the version of this (it was 1.2.17 I think, but had a warning about it being different than the IDE, so I changed it to what it suggested and the warning went away). Even after trying to change it back, I'm still getting the warning below.

`buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'`

I assume this is something simple, but for someone very new to Android/Flutter...etc, I just don't have a clue where to look for the `Unresolved reference: android`, nor have any idea what I did to make it show up.

[image: error]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my case, `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` worked. When Android Studio started back up, the issue was gone. Doesn't really answer the "why", but... it worked.

Comment: after 'Invalidate Caches / Restart' application started to build, but android studio is still complaining about the 'Unresolved reference: android'

Answer (score 8):

Configure to the project SDK to the appropriate API level as per your project will solve your issue(shown in the dialog after clicking Setup SDK at right corner).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For the "Unresolved reference: android” Issue.

It occurs because the project is not able to configure the Android SDK.

```
Go to File-> Project Structure -> Project SDK [Set the correct SDK as per your project]
```

And then,

ReSync the project. (Invalidate caches and restart, if required)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you can try:

open **Android** directory of your flutter project in android studio(new window). Then

1. go to Build and select **clean project**. Then after this select **Rebuild project**.
2. If above step doesn't solves your problem then go to **file -> open ->** select **build.gradle** to reopen and get the dependencies of project.
3. go to project root directory and try **flutter clean** command this would clean the build/ and then try running your project by **flutter run** command.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: In Android Studio 3.2.1, there is no "Build->clean project" nor an option to "Rebuild project". Unless it's in another menu and I just don't see it?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by **updating my Gradle version** to the latest one (via Andorid studio), changing the **ext.kotlin_version to 1.3.11** at build.grade(Project: android), and **updating the SDK** at Tools/SDK Manager/Edit

Answer (score 1):

If you are  still facing Issues like

> Unresolved reference: NonNull
>   or 
>   Unresolved reference: annotation
>   then you should add a dependency to have access to the classes inside `android.support.annotation`
>   Inside your `dependencies` in your `build.gradle`, you should add `com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0`, something like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}
```