# Android side of a Flutter project showing error

Tags: android, flutter

I have a `Flutter` project where, all of a sudden, without me doing anything special as far as I can remember..the Android side has started to show an error, and I am totally lost, I have no idea at all of what is wrong or why that happened.

That is what I see when I open the android folder, the `MainActivity` on the flutter project on android studio:

[image]

I have tried calling `flutter clean`, `restart/invalidate cache`, `gradle clean`...and so far nothing works.

The weird thing is that the project actually runs in the emulator without any problem. And also, if I open the Android part independently on Android Studio i don't see any error.

Anyone had that before?

Android Studio version 3.3.1

Solutions of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992118/unresolved-reference-android-on-new-flutter-project) answer do not work.

** ----- NOTE ----- **

The problem here can be (not sure at all maybe someone else can help here) that I am using a flutter package called `ImagePicker`, which after some code investigation, it turns out that it is using some `AndrodX imports`....and...as far as I am aware of...Flutter is not yet compatible with `AndroidX`.

But i need someone else to confirm that in order to post a solution.

Comment: Did you try to run the application, Sometimes AS shows falsy errors!

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin what do you mean?, of course I ran it many times in emulator and it runs ok, it is mentioned in the question.

Comment: then this just a bug in AS, Sometimes can be solved by clean project, or invalidate cache

Answer (score 2):

This error is not really an error. This happens because android studio is set to read and edit dart not java. In order to edit the android side of a flutter project, you need to click on the android folder -> go to the flutter option -> click 'open in Android Studio'.

This will then allow you to edit the android side of your project.

Comment: hi, thanks, please see my question when i mention: `And also, if I open the Android part independently on Android Studio i don't see any error.`...I am trying to get rid of the "error red mark" on the whole flutter project

Comment: The red error mark, would not reflect an error on the respective Android or iOS sides. This means there is an error somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Set Configure to the Android project SDK of flutter application

Step by Step

1. Click on File -> Project settings then select appropriate API level as per your project will solve your issue

[image]